# MapServer not displaying data from other network locations?

Tags: mapserver, apache, mapfile, ms4w

I have installed MapServer and try to access raster file(.img) from other Network locations (NAS), which is displaying map background color for the mapcanvas.  I have also tried to load the same raster file from local disk and it's loading fine.

Please tell me what are the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are you on Windows as I suppose you are because you use "ms4w" tag, the only solution that I know is to map the network drive and attach it to a drive letter like N: for NAS.

Comment: Ya,like in that way only we are using Map Network drive(N) still we are not getting any response from data..

Comment: Does MapServer user or is it Apache user, have rights?

Comment: It's a apache user, I have checked all rights? please tell if any?

Comment: Have you read this https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/4054? Maybe it helps.

Comment: we have tried as per above, but we are still facing the same issue.